# Highstock scrollbar not covering the whole length in multiple series

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm having an issue with the scrollbar in multiple series line chart where x-axis is date.
Looks like the max length of the scrollbar is determined by the length of the first (older) series.

Although when pressing the 'All' button in range selector I can see all of the series, as the first series ends before the others, as soon as I touch the scrollbar the chart readjusts so that all I can see is the data contained in the first series' length period.

After that, if I want to see the series after the first one has ended, I need to drag the chart or click the 'All' button in range selector again.

I would really appreciate any help you could provide.
Thanks in advance!

```
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8DdP4/2/
```

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo, on the jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it's not supported to cover all series. [Here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2361925-allow-navigator-to-have-multiple-data-series) you can find workarund.

With demo: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/SD4XN/

In short: in callback add series to the navigator on your own:

```
    function (chart) {
        chart.addSeries({
            data: seriesOptions[2].data,
            xAxis: 1,
            yAxis: 1
        });
    }
```

Comment: It works for the scrollbar/navigator problem, but then the added series in the navigator behaves as a chart series, dragging the tooltip towards it while you try to see the chart tooltip. It's kind of crazy. You can see it in the fiddle you linked. If you hide the series we're back to the problem before.

Comment: Simply disable mouse tracking for that series, see: http://jsfiddle.net/SD4XN/23/

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar you refer to is called **navigator**.

There is a property in **navigator** called series which is defined as:

> series: Object
>
> Options for the navigator series. Available options are the same as
>   any series, documented at plotOptions and series.
>
> Unless data is explicitly defined on navigator.series, the data is
>   borrowed from the first series in the chart.

You can see it [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series).

Im not sure if you can build your **navigator** from multiple series, i suppose it is posibles. In case it is not build build the **navigator** with the largest.

Comment: The only thing I've seen that could help me in 'navigator' is to change the base series. But none of the series goes from the first day to the last, so changing to the larger one wouldn't solve the problem. As for the series and xAxis properties, maybe I'm wrong, but I found nothing that could solve it. Thanks!